# Can we draw table in openerp Project/task/description?

Tags: project, task, odoo, openerp-7

I need to create a table in a task, there is no place to do it except description in tasks,
but the problem is I can't find a toold to help me with it.
I tried once to create a table using simple lines like "_" and "|" but every time we want to add things to that table it is **all messed up**;

So is there a solution to add a table to some TASKS descriptions ?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a simple module that overrides the description field of the task to use html. You'll need a model that inherits from `project.task` and redefines the description field like this:

```
_columns = {
    'description': fields.html('Description')
}
```

Then you can use HTML tables in your task description. The downside is that people creating tables need to be familiar with HTML as you will have to write the HTML code by yourself, not using a table tool because the OpenERP HTML editor doesn't provide that option.